# Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, sentiment-analysis, tf-idf

I just do Sentiment Analysis using SVM. The label i use is (positive, negative, and netral). I use this setting
`SVM= svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='poly', gamma='auto')`
I got the accuracy, but why precision and f score being set to 0.0 ? this the warning i got.

```
C:\Users\Niph\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py:1221: 
UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 
in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
```

i tried to use linear kernel too, but the precision and f score always change, sometimes the  precision and f score being set to 0.0 too.

is something wrong with my process in TF_IDF or in the SVM Classification ?

this the code i use for tf-idf

```
Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y = model_selection.train_test_split(data['text_final'],data['label'],test_size=0.3)

Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=5000)
Tfidf_vect.fit(data['text_final'])
Train_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Train_X)
Test_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Test_X)
Train_X_Tfidf.shape
```

and this for SVM Classification

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# Classifier - Algorithm - SVM
# fit the training dataset on the classifier
svclassifier = svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='linear', gamma='auto')
svclassifier.fit(Train_X_Tfidf, Train_Y)
y_pred = svclassifier.predict(Test_X_Tfidf)


# Use accuracy_score function to get the accuracy
print("SVM Accuracy Score -> ",accuracy_score(y_pred, Test_Y)*100)
print
print (classification_report(Test_Y, y_pred))
print
print ("Confusion matrix")
print (metrics.confusion_matrix(Test_Y, y_pred))
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve], showing the data that you’re providing to your F-score function.

Comment: Please read the error message closely; your model fails to predict some classes - so the non-existence of these classes in the predictions renders the precisoon and  F score undefined. Also, including here a bunch of `print` statements without their outputs is hardly helpful for any respondent.